# Remove curly braces from xpath output in Postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql

Let's say I'm parsing an XML using this

```
SELECT xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml);
```

And the output would be

```
xpath
-------
{45687}
```

How do I have it output without the curly braces *efficiently*? And by efficiently, I mean not having to use a regexp_replace() function like

```
SELECT regexp_replace(xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml)::text, '[{}]', '', 'g');
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`xpath()` doesn't return a string, it returns an `xml[]`. The curly braces are part of the array notation, not part of the data - you're adding them yourself with the `text` cast.

For a fixed-size array, you can pull the elements out by index:

```
SELECT (xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml))[1]
```

Generalising this to an arbitrary number of elements, you might do something like this:

```
SELECT string_agg(x::text, ',')
FROM unnest(xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml)) u(x)
```

Though this may not be more efficient than your original version. The simplest way to do this via string manipulation is probably

```
SELECT btrim(xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml)::text, '{}')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for multiple alternative ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found what seems to be a better way. Since xpath returns what seems like an array result in Postgres, I just case the xpath output to an array and use unnest to extract that value. It makes sense for xpath to output the values with curly braces because there could be many instances of the element that I'm extracting from. So another way to do it would be

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml)::varchar[]);
```